# French characters inside JavaScript inside HTML inside XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an .xsl file that has HTML that looks like this:

```
<input onblur="resetText(this,'octobre à décembre')" />
```

Obviously, this wouldn't work as is and so I have to escape it. This is what I've tried:

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[
  <input onblur="resetText(this,'octobre &agrave; d&eacute;cembre')" />
]]></xsl:text>
```

This doesn't work and I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in the browser.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Post your `resetText()` code

Comment: It's not the `resetText` code that's the issue. I've tried it without the French characters (i.e. `resetText(this,'october a decembre')`) and it renders fine without the error. It's the way I'm encoding French characters in JavaScript inside an HTML element inside XML which I'm at a lost.

Comment: Okay, if you insist. What happens when using `octobre &#38;#224; d&#38;#233;cembre` instead

Comment: if you use xslt, then you can't use HTML entitites, you need to use the char-code-based XML entities (no name) instead

Comment: @elzi No errors, but renders as `octobre &#224; d&#233;cembre`. Hmm. I guess I'll just modify `resetText` then to be able to work with an input like this if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

> Obviously, this wouldn't work as is

There is nothing obvious about it. In XSLT, you can use Unicode characters without escaping (provided your encoding is UTF-8 or similar). You **cannot** use undefined entities such as `&agrave;`.

If you need the output to escape the accented characters to HTML entities, try setting your output method to HTML (may not work with every XSLT processor).

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert at this but I wonder if you're making the browser know what character encoding to use ?

I'd use UTF-8

Make sure to save/convert the file as utf-8 and make sure you specify character encoding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't post `resetText()` but here's the one I came up with that made things work:

```
// remove second param when calling from onblur 
// assumes input value has decoded html entities

function resetText(input) {
    var rawStr = input.value;
    var encodedStr = rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
       return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
    });

    input.value = encodedStr;
}
```